# Book recommendations on OPL

Tags: cplex, reference-request, books, opl

Are there any good books that teach how to work with OPL in CPLEX? I searched but I didn't find any.

Comment: When you say "teach CPLEX" what do you mean? Do you mean the modelling language OPL or more generally how to use CPLEX from several different API's?

Comment: @Sune I mean OPL.

Comment: then you should probably edit your question to reflect this, as it would probably lead more qualified answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many useful references that can be found by googling. In the following you can find some of them:

- [IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio OPL Language User’s Manual](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.studio.help/pdf/opl_languser.pdf)
- [Introduction to Computational Optimization Models for Production Planning in a Supply Chain](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540298786)
- [A Deep Dive into Strategic Network Design](http://networkdesignbook.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/A-Deep-Dive-Into-Strategic-Network-Design-Programming-by-Cacioppi-and-Watson.pdf)

PS: About the first mentioned reference, it is about (V-12.8) that I knew the last version is 20.1. I hope they will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

There is a rather helpful list of educational resources specific to IBM Decision Optimization products [here](https://medium.com/@AlainChabrier/decision-optimization-education-a50cada93856). If you scroll down a bit, you will find links to some YouTube videos about optimization modeling using OPL (and the CPLEX Studio IDE).

Answer (score 4):

I recommand the Model Building Book by Williams and here you may see the [examples in OPL](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/model-building-oplcplex-alex-fleischer/).

[image: Model Building]

Let me add some OPL links:

- [How to with OPL ?](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-opl-alex-fleischer/)
- [Tips and tricks](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/tips-tricks-opl-cplex-alex-fleischer/)
- [OPL Scripting](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/javascript-within-opl-cplex-alex-fleischer/)
- [OPL and Excel](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/excel-rocket-science-optimization-alex-fleischer/)
- [Making Optimization Simple](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a book that Pete Cacioppi wrote to [teach OPL](http://networkdesignbook.com/academic-use/new-book-teach-cplex-and-optimization-along-with-network-design/) and optimization as it relates to network design models. It was meant for beginners. It uses a network design problem as the example, but you don't need to get the Supply Chain Network Design book to use this one.

Comment: Thanks. But somebody else mentioned this book before.

Comment: @Emad.  Whoops.  Good catch.  Sorry about that.  Hopefully, I added a little bit of context :-)

Comment: Yes. That was useful.